# glibc cross-compiling for ARM target fails at linking if THUMB used

Tags: arm, glibc, thumb

I’m trying to build cross-gcc for arm family.

Whole multistep process i'm using of building 9.3gcc cross-gcc works ok and building working system for: i386, x86_64, aarch64 and ARM - but fails in ARM for THUMB case.

gcc9.3.0 cross-compiler I’m using to build glibc is build with multi-lib and provides following multi-libs:

```
arm/v5te/hard;@marm@march=armv5te+fp@mfloat-abi=hard
thumb/nofp;@mthumb@mfloat-abi=soft
thumb/v7/nofp;@mthumb@march=armv7@mfloat-abi=soft
thumb/v7+fp/softfp;@mthumb@march=armv7+fp@mfloat-abi=softfp
thumb/v7+fp/hard;@mthumb@march=armv7+fp@mfloat-abi=hard
thumb/v7-r+fp.sp/softfp;@mthumb@march=armv7-r+fp.sp@mfloat-abi=softfp
thumb/v7-r+fp.sp/hard;@mthumb@march=armv7-r+fp.sp@mfloat-abi=hard
thumb/v7-a/nofp;@mthumb@march=armv7-a@mfloat-abi=soft
thumb/v7-a+fp/softfp;@mthumb@march=armv7-a+fp@mfloat-abi=softfp
thumb/v7-a+fp/hard;@mthumb@march=armv7-a+fp@mfloat-abi=hard
thumb/v7-a+simd/softfp;@mthumb@march=armv7-a+simd@mfloat-abi=softfp
thumb/v7-a+simd/hard;@mthumb@march=armv7-a+simd@mfloat-abi=hard
thumb/v7ve+simd/softfp;@mthumb@march=armv7ve+simd@mfloat-abi=softfp
thumb/v7ve+simd/hard;@mthumb@march=armv7ve+simd@mfloat-abi=hard
thumb/v8-a/nofp;@mthumb@march=armv8-a@mfloat-abi=soft
thumb/v8-a+simd/softfp;@mthumb@march=armv8-a+simd@mfloat-abi=softfp
thumb/v8-a+simd/hard;@mthumb@march=armv8-a+simd@mfloat-abi=hard
```

Building glibc 2.31 for ARM works ok for target:

**-marm -march=armv5te+fp -mfloat-abi=softfp**

Build fails however (with the same error) for any ARM target with THUMB i.e.:

**-mthumb -march=armv7 -mfloat-abi=soft**

linking error with THUMB is following:

```
      -Wl,-z,combreloc -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--hash-style=both -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,-z,now    \
      /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/script/devel/glibc/work/main.d/glibc-2.31_build/elf/librtld.os -Wl,--version-script=/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/script/devel/glibc/work/main.d/glibc-2.31_build/ld.map        \
      -Wl,-soname=ld-linux.so.3         \
      -Wl,-defsym=_begin=0
/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/arm-minimyth-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/../../../../arm-minimyth-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/script/devel/glibc/work/main.d/glibc-2.31_build/elf/librtld.os: in function `init_tls':
rtld.c:(.text+0x520): undefined reference to `__libc_do_syscall'
/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/arm-minimyth-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/../../../../arm-minimyth-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/script/devel/glibc/work/main.d/glibc-2.31_build/elf/librtld.os: in function `dl_main':
rtld.c:(.text+0x2426): undefined reference to `__libc_do_syscall'
/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/arm-minimyth-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/../../../../arm-minimyth-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/script/devel/glibc/work/main.d/glibc-2.31_build/elf/librtld.os: in function `_dl_lookup_symbol_x':
(.text+0x798c): undefined reference to `__libc_do_syscall'
/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/arm-minimyth-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/../../../../arm-minimyth-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/script/devel/glibc/work/main.d/glibc-2.31_build/elf/librtld.os: in function `_dl_relocate_object':
(.text+0x913e): undefined reference to `__libc_do_syscall'
/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/arm-minimyth-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/../../../../arm-minimyth-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/script/devel/glibc/work/main.d/glibc-2.31_build/elf/librtld.os: in function `_dl_fixup':
(.text+0xabac): undefined reference to `__libc_do_syscall'
/home/piotro/minimyth-dev/images/build/usr/lib/gcc/arm-minimyth-linux-gnueabi/9.3.0/../../../../arm-minimyth-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: /home/piotro/minimyth-dev/script/devel/glibc/work/main.d/glibc-2.31_build/elf/librtld.os:(.text+0xafc0): more undefined references to `__libc_do_syscall' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As whole (exactly the same building procedure with exactly the same sources+scripts) works ok for: i386, x86_64, aarch64 and non-THUMB ARM targets - failed ARM builds for targets with THUMB I’m considering as bug in glibc.

Only thing to trigger failure is change compiler flags from **-marm** to **-mthumb**

I already filled glibc bug report for this (#25920) - but decided to ask here as conversation on glibc bug tracker seems to be a bit non-effective...

Maybe somebody has idea how to move forward with this?

Comment: no its how the libraries were built and combined with the rest of the toolchain.  you can also build the armv5 for thumb, what happened when you tried that?  did it link in arm mode libraries or thumb mode?   because there are different instructions, the desire would be to have different libraries and the toolchain and/or command line options need to get that all straight.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like glibc needs small patch to successfully cross-compile for armv7-a targets: https://github.com/warpme/minimyth2/blob/master/script/devel/glibc/files/glibc-2.31-fix-building-arm-thumb.patch.

With above patch I tested cross-compilation for following list of targets with success:

```
-marm   -march=armv5te+fp   -mfloat-abi=softfp
-mthumb -march=armv7-a      -mfloat-abi=soft
-mthumb -march=armv7-a+fp   -mfloat-abi=softfp
-mthumb -march=armv7-a+simd -mfloat-abi=softfp
-mthumb -march=armv7ve+simd -mfloat-abi=softfp
```